# Java сервер для приложения на J2ME

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket, веб-сервер

Пытаюсь написать сервер на `Java` для опроса и управления кое-какими железяками с `GPRS`-модемами на `J2ME`. Сейчас реализовал сайт для отображения информации на `Spring MVC` и задеплоил его на `TomCat`.
Застрял на реализации длительного соединения с клиентами в отдельных потоках для обмена данными (клиентов будет до 100). Никак не могу найти толковый пример для моего случая с использованием `Spring` и `Tomcat` (все примеры для создания сайтов), концепция в принципе похожая, но все равно ладу ей дать не могу. Подскажите в какую сторону думать или может я вообще не правильно выбрал технологии для реализации этой задачи?

Comment: Для чего вам нужно длительное соединение? И какими данными клиент делится с сервером?

Comment: @JVic, данные - массив байтов `ASCII`. А на счет длительного соединения, я рассуждал так: из-за того что на стороне клиента стоит `GRPS` с динамическим IP отправить данные с сервера (без запроса от клиента) не получится, по-этому нужно как можно дольше держать клиента на связи, на случай если захочется им поуправлять.

Comment: @Kozmin Alexandr - если  у тебя tomcat - у него есть хорошая библиотека для работы по websocket. просто подключи и используй. можно http://tootallnate.github.io/Java-WebSocket/ . есть пример и для андроида

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC - это web-фреймворк, соответственно он предназначен для работы с протоколом http, а протокол http не предназначен для длительного удержания соединения, он работает в режиме запрос-ответ. Вам больше подойдёт обмен данными на уровне tcp-сокетов. Если соединений предполагается много, то лучше на асинхронных сокетах. Посмотрите в сторону Netty.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что в моем случае будет 2 сервера: один для сайта (`Spring MVC`), а второй для общения с клиентами по tcp-сокетам (`netty`)?

Comment: Ну, если вам нужен сайт для людей, то да. А если нужно только общаться с устройствами, то Spring MVC вообще не нужен.

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше организовать связь между этими двумя серверами? Например, устройства опрашиваются tcp-сервером раз в час и данные записываются в общую БД, новые данные отображаются на сайте. Тут вроде все понятно. А вот если нужно с сайта изменить что-то в устройстве? Для этого мне нужно отправить массив байтов `ASCII` с сервера на `Spring MVC` на tcp-сервер, как такое реализовать? Нигде не находил примера, чтобы отправлять данные со спринга на конкретный url. Или нужно с tcp-сервера, периодически делать запрос, типа: "а не изменилось ли что-то?"

Comment: В случае Netty каждое устройство при загрузке просто должно открывать tcp-соединение с сервером и не закрывать его до отключения. В случае разрыва переподключаться. Тогда и сервер сможет устройствам отправить что угодно в любой момент и периодические опросы не нужны, можно передавать данные в режиме реального времени. Так сделан [blynk-server](https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server), например.

Comment: Если у вас есть отдельно сайт на Spring MVC для отображения данных устройств людям и управления устройствами людьми, то я бы добавил в сервисный слой асинхронную отправку событий, в слушателях этих событий сделал бы передачу сообщений серверу очередей (типа Redis), а в коде Netty-сервера обработчик поступления сообщений из очереди.

Comment: Спасибо, буду двигаться в этом направлении)